# Optimization of apply

Tags: r, optimization, apply

I have existing code that calculates concordance value for a dataframe/matrix. It's basically the number of rows where all the values are the same over the total number of rows.

```
...
concordance<-new[complete.cases(new),] #removes rows with NAs
TF<-apply(concordance, 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x))>1) F else T)
#outputs vector of T/F if it is concordant
numF<-table(TF)["TRUE"]#gets number of trues
concValue<-numF/NROW(TF) #true/total
...
```

Above is what I have now. It runs ok but I was wondering if there was any way to make it faster.

Edit: Dimensions of object is variable, but # of cols are typically 2-6 and there are typically 1,000,000+ rows. This is part of a package i'm developing so input data is variable.

Comment: `if(...) F else T` ---> `!(...)` or just `(length(unique(x)) == 1L)` (no need for `if`/`else`)

Comment: also ```mean(TF)``` is better than ```numF<-table(TF)["TRUE"];concValue<-numF/NROW(TF)```

Comment: There are different tricks to get around apply. Can you please describe the dimensions of the objects on which you are usually running this code so that we know which tricks may be useful in your situation

Comment: Post has been edited @GradaGukovic

Comment: I've done several benchmarking tests (`3 x 1e5` dim) using yours plus variants of `mean(apply(dat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) != 1L)`, and they are within milliseconds of each other (max diff is under 10%). I'd think you're about as maxed out with `apply` as you can be, though I think the above recommendations (`mean`) are certainly better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the number of rows is much larger than the number of columns it makes sense to loop on columns instead, dropping rows, where there is more than different one value in the process:

```
propIdentical <- function(Mat){
    nrowInit <- nrow(Mat)  

    for(i in 1:(ncol(Mat) - 1)){
       if(!nrow(Mat)) break #stop if the matrix has no rows
       else{
            #check which elements of column i and column i+1 are equal:
            equals <- Mat[,i] == Mat[, i+1] 

            # remove all other rows from the matrix
            Mat <- Mat[equals,,drop = F]
       }
    }

    return(nrow(Mat)/nrowInit)
}
```

some tests:

```
set.seed(1)

# normal case
dat <- matrix(sample(1:10, rep = T, size = 3*10^6), nrow = 10^6)
system.time(prI <- propIdentical(dat)) ; prI

 user  system elapsed 
 0.053   0.017   0.070 
[1] 0.009898

# normal case on my pc for comparison:
system.time(app <- mean(apply(dat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1L)); app
   user  system elapsed 
 12.176   0.036  12.231 
[1] 0.009898

# worst case
dat <- matrix(1L, nrow = 10^6, ncol = 6)
> system.time(prI <- propIdentical(dat)) ; prI
   user  system elapsed 
  0.302   0.044   0.348 
[1] 1
# worst case on my pc for comparison
system.time(mean(apply(dat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1L))
   user  system elapsed 
 12.562   0.001  12.578

# testing drop = F and if(!nrow(Mat)) break
dat <- matrix(1:2, ncol = 2)
> system.time(prI <- propIdentical(dat)) ; prI
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
[1] 0
```

Note: if you run this on a `data.frame` make sure to turn it into a matrix first.